# clear my own app defaults programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible in android 4.0 and higher to programmatically clear your own app's defaults?  can someone point me in the right direction if possible

Comment: What do you mean by `defaults`?

Comment: same "defaults" that you can clear by going to Settings>ManageApplication>some app - "clear defaults"  like when an app is set as default launcher or sharer of mages

Comment: He probably means file-types that are set to open via his application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761553/clear-application-defaults

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot set your app as the default for an action programmatically in any version of Android.

This is for security reasons, as a malicious app could exploit this to become the default for any user action, and steal personal information, or render the device useless etc.

At best, on your first run you could launch a chooser intent with dummy data and ask the user to set your app as the default.

EDIT:

My mistake. I thought you wanted to set the defaults.

[clearPackagePreferredActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29) in `PackageManager` will clear the defaults of a particular app, whichever's package name you pass.

Comment: i know that i can not SET the default, but can i clear its defaults programmatically

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761553/clear-application-defaults

Answer (score 2):

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().commit();
```