# How to delete default Share App in Delphi code?

Tags: android, delphi, button, share, default

I am creating an Android Application in Delphi, and I need a Button, which deletes the default Share App, if one is set.

E.g
I share a File via Gmail, and press 'Always'
The next time, this is the default app.

Is it possible to delete this in Code? Or can i open the App-Infos where it is possible to reset this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [clearPackagePreferredActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29) in `PackageManager` will clear the defaults of a particular app, whichever's package name you pass.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072877/6517492)

2. You can open the application settings screen programmatically. Java code:

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
   Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
   intent.setData(uri);
   context.startActivity(intent);

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35456817/6517492)

Comment: Is it possible to get the Package name of the Application, which is used as the default share for ACTION_SEND?

Comment: The [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) API contains getPreferredActivities

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPreferredActivities(java.util.List%3Candroid.content.IntentFilter%3E,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.content.ComponentName%3E,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: I have solved the Problem with resolveActivity on the PackageManager. Thank you @mjn42 for the tip!